# Receiving unhandled NULL exception when using curl_easy_cleanup(curl)

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I have a Unity application that uses a c++ plugin that I wrote for making http requests. This plugin uses curl libraries.

As per curl documentation, they recommend using curl_easy_cleanup(curl) as the last command, in order to free the handle and clean up all the resources.

Here's my code that makes a simple http POST request:

```
struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
CURL *curl = NULL;
curl  = curl_easy_init();
int httpCode(0);

if(curl)
{
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "charsets: utf-8");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    //Set remote URL
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, endpoint.c_str());

    std::string params;
    for(std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string>::iterator it = parameters.begin(); it != parameters.end(); ++it)
    {
        params = it->first + ": " + it->second + " ";
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, (const char *)params.c_str());
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, jsonObject.c_str());
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, ResponseRecievedCallback);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpCode);

//Uncommenting this line makes my application crash

    //curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

However when I add this line, my unity app crashes with this following exception:

```
 Receiving unhandled NULL exception
Obtained 13 stack frames.
#0  0x000001207a4438 in Curl_expire_clear
#1  0x00000120790e25 in Curl_close
```

I've spent the past couple of days online searching for some solution, read curl documentation but couldn't find any help. I'd appreciate if someone can explain why this might crash?

Thanks much!

Comment: I'm going to ask a likely totally unrelated question: why cast `(const char *)params.c_str()` ? Just curious what problem that was supposed to be fixing.

Comment: This was just a choice I made to use strings, so I could easily concatenate with + operator to append parameters. But this is completely unrelated to the problem I am facing.

Comment: `Curl_expire_clear()` only does stuff with handles being used in multi mode, otherwise it returns right away. Running your program in a debugger (With a debug-enabled libcurl of course) would help narrow it down more, as would showing your `ResponseReceivedCallback`, but it smells like you have a buffer overflow somewhere that's overwriting part of the curl structure. Maybe also try running it through valgrind?

Comment: Thanks for the response! All that ResponseReceivedCallback does is save the incoming json response as a string: std::size_t ResponseRecievedCallback(const char* in, size_t size, size_t num, std::string* out)
{
    const std::size_t totalBytes(size * num);
    response_string = in;
    return totalBytes;
}
I have never used Valgrind and thanks for the pointers! Let me check it out.

Comment: Fyi, `response_string = in;` is wrong. That `num` is there for a reason. There is no guarantee the received request is terminated (unless you also sent a terminator, and even then, it may be coming in a separate frame). You should be using `std::string response_string(in, in+num);`

Comment: I found something more: commenting out this line: curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpCode); prevents the crash. I looked up the  documentation on capturing the httpCode, and updated my code to this: if(res == CURLE_OK) {
            curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpCode);
        } 

It doesn't seem to help though. I am still getting a crash with that line. How else can I capture the httpCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the issue by making httpCode a long instead of an int (per documentation). I must've overlooked it before!